# Compute $\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x}{1+x^2} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I tried to compute the integral by using the substitution $x=e^y$ but I couldn't find an answer (I checked it converges by checking limits at both ends by using the comparison test).

Answer (score 4):

Split the integral into the intervals $(0, 1)$ and $(1, +\infty)$. Hence,

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln x}{1+x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x &= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln x}{1+x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x  + \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln x}{1+x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x \\ 
 &= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}  + \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln \frac{1}{x}}{1+\left ( \frac{1}{x} \right )^2} \frac{1}{x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x \\ 
 &= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln x}{1+x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x - \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln x}{1+x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x \\ 
 &= 0 
\end{align*}

and this is your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You were thinking about a correct substitution. Indeed: $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{y e^y dy}{1+e^{2y}}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{y dy}{e^{-y}+e^{y}}=0.$$

Comment: Thank you! But why is the last part equal to 0 ?

Comment: The integrated function is odd (changes sign under $y\to-y$).